# How to set Image to Canvas type object

Tags: android, canvas

i want to set background image instead of **canvas = null** please help me to do it. I have posted the code i used.

```
public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
        //begin infinite loop while(running=true)
        while (running) {
            canvas = null;
            // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
            // in the surface
            try {
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    // update game state 
                    this.gamePanel.update();
                    // render state to the screen
                    // draws the canvas on the panel
                    this.gamePanel.render(canvas);              
                }
            } finally {
                // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
                // an inconsistent state
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }   // end finally
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: draw the bitmap on to the canvas. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: @Raghunandan here i want to set my Canvas as background thats why i locked my canvas